# Why do I get `None` results from this `lambda`?

Tags: python

I am trying to write the `lambda` based equivalent of Python functions as a learning exercise.

I have this working code, which takes a list and returns a new list with unique elements:

```
def unique_list(l):
    x = []
    for a in l:
        if a not in x:
            x.append(a)
    return x
```

When I test it, I get the expected result:

```
>>> print(unique_list([1,1,1,2,2,3,3]))
[1, 2, 3]
```

But my attempt at replacing this with `lambda`, as follows:

```
a = lambda l, x=[]:[x.append(a) for a in l if a not in x]
```

gives the wrong result:

```
>>> a([1,1,1,2,2,3,3]) 
[None, None, None]
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: `list.append` returns `None`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Aside from the linked duplicate, please note how I [edit]ed the question, as a model for how to ask clearly and concisely.

Comment: As a side note: the problem doesn't actually have anything to do with `lambda`. You could just as easily reproduce the problem like `def a(l): x= []; return [x.append(a) for a in l if a not in x]`. Perhaps seeing it written this way makes the problem more clear.

Comment: Also, for the specific task in this code, please also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214.